# GcmListenerService backward compatibility

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Google recently updated its play-service to 7.5 version which includes addition of GcmListenerService, InstanceID and some other API changes. I want to know if this will be backward compatible with the devices having play service version older than 7.5 ?

Might be a basic question but I haven't find a way through it. Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

If this API is available from GPS 7.5, and you need it, you have to be sure that the device has that version of GPS. Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client), in particular to "Handle connection failures". This is the right way to proceed: don't care about the GPS version, just use the last one and make sure that the device has the last one too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work. I don't think older devices are officially supported, but I have managed to get an app working using the new libraries on a Gingerbread device even though it had an old version of Google Play Services on it.